# form.$valid is working for "required" but it's not working for ngPattern and maxlength.

Tags: angularjs

If zipcode is empty then form is invalid so button is disabled but if zipcode is 2 digits error message is showing but form is showing as valid in controller. If zipcode is empty then I need to disable button but I'm checking form valid or not but dont worry about ng-disabled. I just need solution for showing the "div" if and only if form is valid.

```js
 function submitUserDetail (formValid) {
      if(formValid) {
      $scope.showDiv = true;
      }
    }
```

```html
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <label required>
                        Zip code required
                    </label>
                    <label pattern>
                        Invalid Zip code
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <input type="tel" maxlength="5" class="" name="zip5"
                           ng-model="userDetail.zipCode" required=""
                           pattern="^\d{5}$"
                           data-validate-on-blur="true" value=""
                           size="5">
                    <span class="" title="Reset" onclick="jQuery(this).prev('input').val('').trigger('change');"></span>
                </div>
            </div>        
        
        
        <div class="">
            <div class="">
                <div class="">
                    <span class=""></span>
                    <button class="" href="#" id="button" ng-click="submitUserDetail(form.$valid)" ng-disabled="form.$invalid">See section</button>
                    <span class=""></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div ng-if="showDiv">
        .......
        </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a `<form>` wrapping the HTML provided.

If so, you should make sure your `<form`> tag has `novalidate` applied so you're using AngularJS form validation and not HTML5 form validation:

```
 <form name="form" ng-submit="submitUserDetail(form.$valid)" novalidate>
```

Also, it looks like you're mixing HTML5 validation attributes with AngularJS validation attributes. You should be using `ng-required` and `ng-pattern` instead of `required` and `pattern`.

Comment: @sanju Make sure you're using AngularJS validation directives then

Comment: Yes I'm using ang directives. I'm able to see the error messages so the validation is happening